# Avoid optional dictionaries checks in loop

Tags: python

Eg. i have a generator and want to extend each pair with function params from a dictionary if it's available else use Nones.

```
gen = ((k,v) for k, v in enumerate('abcde'))
def func(k, v, w x, y, z): pass
```

I can check if each dict as argument source is available and use previous generator to fulfill its pairs with dict values or Nones:

```
dicts = ({}, None, {}, None)
extend_pairs = lambda get, gen: ((k, v, get(k)) for k, v in gen) if get else ((*p, None) for p in gen)
for d in (dicts):
    # use extra function to pass each iteration variable instead of last one
    get = extend_pairs(d and d.get, gen)
results = [func(*args) for args in gen]
```

But even simpler would bo to check all dictionaries availability first and then fulfill pairs with dynamically generated function that returns all dict values or Nones at once.

```
sources = tuple(x.get if isinstance(x, dict) else None for x in dicts)
# then dynamically create function with exec to get args and it works just like below:
if any(sources):
    get_args = lambda k, v: k, v, sources[0](k), None, sources[2](None) # ...
else:
    get_args = None
results = [func(*get_args(*p) for p in gen] if get_args else [func(*p) for p in gen]
```

It's not something i really need, just a personal curiosity. When it's a case of function with keyword only arguments i could use pipeline yielding kwargs dictionary or even list in above case, but is it how should i handle this kind of problem or is there a better, more efficient way to do it?

Comment: Sounds like you want zip or itertools.ziplongest https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest

Comment: @DyRuss yes, it is a solution but i will have to store gen and create each func param generator with extra lookup if dictionary is available, then zip it. And i wonder if this extra lookup of gen data on each dictionary is possible to avoid.